# How to populate combo box with values relevant to the record being edited

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access

First, I designate group ID's:

[image]

Then I fill out the 2nd table with names and assign each name to a group:

[image]

So then I would like to go back to table #1 and assign the Head to each group with the following conditions:

1. Set the Head field to a Lookup Combo box to display only names that are present
   in the database (since this is a prerequisite: "Head must be a
   member") - **This I can do**
2. Combo box should display
   only the names already assigned to this particular group (another
   prerequisite: "Only member of the group can be its Head") - **This I
   can not do**

It would seem that the correct SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT [Table #2].[NameID], [Table #2].[Name] FROM Table #2 

WHERE [Table #2].[GroupID] = [Table #1].[GroupID] ORDER BY [Name];
```

But it does not work. Is this possible or am I creating circular references and I should use some other tools?

Comment: Do not use lookup fields: [The Evils of Lookup Fields in Tables](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm). Create a form based on your groups table. Create a subform based on your names table. Connect both forms based on GroupID. Enter data per group. You should not enter data manually in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your SQL statement is due to you trying to use the group ID from table one without joining it, the following SQL statement should work:

```
    SELECT t2.NameID , t2.Name
    FROM [Table #1] as t1
    RIGHT JOIN [Table #2] as t2 on t1.groupid = t2.groupid
```